# Encrypted home folder - How to home folder after 10.10 reload?

Tags: encryption

I am using Ubuntu 10.10 and I set the home folder to be encrypted whenever I installed my system.

Unfortunately, I forgot I encrypted the home folder and I reinstalled 10.10. Now I can't access my old home folder.

How can I get my data back?

Comment: you'll need that long password you were asked to save on the first login, without that you can't.

Answer (score 3):

Try this: http://blog.dustinkirkland.com/2011/04/introducing-ecryptfs-recover-private.html

Or this: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EncryptedPrivateDirectory#Recovering%20Your%20Data%20Manually

Hope this helps!